# Perl issue with local::lib

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to use [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/module/local%3a%3alib) as I don't have rights on the system and I have downloaded a local library and used bootstrap technique.

```
perl Makefile.PL --bootstrap
make test && make install
echo 'eval $(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)' >>~/.bashrc
```

After this I tried to download Module and it is stored in `/home/perl5/man/man3`

But when I run the script I get an error and it seems its taking the old path. When I run the same command on my system it does take the local library and the script is running correctly.

```
Can't locate Net/Patricia.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at nettest.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at nettest.pl line 2.
-bash-3.2$
```

Comment: How do you run the script? Is this another user? Show the local lib configuration: `echo PATH=$PATH ; env|sort|grep PERL`

Comment: PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
 use Net::Patricia;
   my $pt = new Net::Patricia;
   $pt->add_string('192.168.0.0/25');
   $pt->add_string('192.168.0.0/16');
   print $pt->match_string('192.168.0.0/24'), "\n";

perl hi.pl

I am using in my LAB with same login but on server I am facing issue while ssh but on local lab system my script working.

Comment: This shows that when you run the script, it lacks the configuration made in `~/.bashrc`. Find out why `~/.bashrc` is not executed.

Comment: if i only run this ~/.bashrc bash: /homes/de214/.bashrc: Permission denied

Is it due to restriction on that particular machine. And is there any other way i can make local lib work

Comment: please, cut your ~/.bashrc file and update your question

Comment: Sorry I did not understand to cut ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: Copy the contents of your `~/.bashrc` file, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17920101/edit), and paste/add the content of your `~/.bashrc` file to the question.

Answer (score 0):

did you use this at the beginning of your script?

```
use local::lib;
```

or, if installed in other location, for example:

```
use local::lib '~/foo';
```

Comment: yes now used with local lib
   use local::lib;
   use Net::Patricia;
   my $pt = new Net::Patricia;
   $pt->add_string('192.168.0.0/25');
   $pt->add_string('192.168.0.0/16');
   print $pt->match_string('192.168.0.0/24'), "\n";
Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at sai.pl l

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you can also just reference the location of modules you need without using local::lib. That will simplify the situation for debugging, but could also be a permanent solution as well. Just add this to the top of the script:

```
# Path to directory that contains the 'Net' folder.
use lib '/path/to/my/modules';
```